# Why does this regex capture spaces?

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am currently trying to validate a username for a website on the submission of a sign up form.

The regex for the username is `([^a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,25})`. I call `preg_match` on the username in PHP along with this regex.

For some reason, spaces pass through undetected. I have tried a negative lookahead as follows: `(?![a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,25})` but still had no look.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: So The username should not have `a-zA-Z0-9_` in it, check place of `^`. Validate you regex http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: You probably meant: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,25}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `[^...]` is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any char *other than*  those defined in the class. So, `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` matches any char other than alphanumeric or `_` chars.

What you want to use is a *positive* character class, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, or `\w` (without the `/u` modifier, `\w` matches the same chars), and also *anchors*.

So, you may use

```
preg_match('~^\w{5,25}$~', $s)
```

Or

```
preg_match('~\A\w{5,25}\z~', $s)
```

The `\z` anchor matches the very end of string, while `$` (without the `/D` modifier) can also match before a trailing newline (LF) char.